# Issue with for-loop running through JSON

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary, for-loop

I cannot seem to get Python to print data from JSON by running it through a for-loop.

I would like to run a for-loop through the JSON file, and have it print the value of the 'familyName' key from each item in the list.

When I print the value of the 'familyName' key for one item in the list..

```
print((results_information["MRData"]["StandingsTable"]["StandingsLists"][0]["DriverStandings"][0]["Driver"]["familyName"])
```

..I get the result I am looking for:

```
Hamilton
```

However, when I try and use a for-loop to get the 'familyName' from each item in the list..

```
for i in (results_information["MRData"]["StandingsTable"]["StandingsLists"][0]["DriverStandings"]):
            print([0]["Driver"]["familyName"])
```

..it gives an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\F1App\f1.py", line 58, in <module>
    getUserInput(input('Please enter your selection: '))
  File "D:\Python\F1App\f1.py", line 32, in getUserInput
    print([0]["Driver"]["givenName"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This confuses me because it works when printed on it's own, but not as a for-loop. I am assuming I have used incorrect syntax.

Thank you in advance.

Here is a link to the JSON file:
http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/driverStandings.json

Here is all of my code if required:

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get('http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/driverStandings.json')
results_information = r.json()
q = requests.get('http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/next.json')
next_circuit = q.json()
s = requests.get('http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last.json')
last_circuit = s.json()

status = True

def getUserInput(number):
    if number == '1':
        print()
        print("The leader of the driver standings for the current F1 season is:")
        print((results_information["MRData"]["StandingsTable"]["StandingsLists"][0]["DriverStandings"][0]["Driver"]["givenName"]) + " " + (results_information["MRData"]["StandingsTable"]["StandingsLists"][0]["DriverStandings"][0]["Driver"]["familyName"]))
    elif number == '2':
        print()
        print("The leader of the constructor standings for the current F1 season is:")
        print(results_information["MRData"]["StandingsTable"]["StandingsLists"][0]["DriverStandings"][0]["Constructors"][0]["name"])
    elif number == '3':
        print()
        print(('The next race of the current season will be the ') + (next_circuit['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races'][0]['raceName']))
    elif number == '4':
        print()
        print(('The previous race of the current season was the ') + (last_circuit['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races'][0]['raceName']))
    elif number == '5':
        print()
        print('Here are the driver standings for the current F1 season:')
        for i in (results_information["MRData"]["StandingsTable"]["StandingsLists"][0]["DriverStandings"]):
            print([0]["Driver"]["familyName"])
    elif number.lower() == 'e':
        print()
        print('Goodbye.')
        print()
        exit()
    else:
        print()
        print('Please enter a valid input.')
        print()

while status == True:
    print('----------------------------')
    print('Welcome to the F1 Python App')
    print('----------------------------')
    print()

    print('------------MENU------------')
    print('----------------------------')
    print('Enter \'1\' for leader of the driver standings for the current F1 season.')
    print('Enter \'2\' for leader of the constructor standings for the current F1 season.')
    print('Enter \'3\' for location of the upcoming race circuit in the current F1 season.')
    print('Enter \'4\' for location of the previous race circuit in the current F1 season.')
    print('Enter \'5\' for the driver standings for the current F1 season.')
    print('Enter \'E\' to exit the application.')
    print()
    getUserInput(input('Please enter your selection: '))
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback of the error, instead of just the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pay attention to the line the error message is telling you about. I think you meant:

```
print(i["Driver"]["familyName"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the variable `i` instead of `[0]` like this:

```
for i in (results_information["MRData"]["StandingsTable"]["StandingsLists"][0]["DriverStandings"]):
            print(i["Driver"]["familyName"])
```

The reason being the value of `results_information["MRData"]["StandingsTable"]["StandingsLists"][0]["DriverStandings"]`
at each iteration is stored in the variable `i`. You then access it through `i["Driver"]["familyName"]`. You do not need `[0]` as the for loop is already iterating through the list.

Answer (score -2):

You have shown in the first line that

```
(results_information["MRData"]["StandingsTable"]["StandingsLists"][0]["DriverStandings"][0]["Driver"]["familyName"]
```

is equal to the string

```
Hamilton
```

Hence, your error occurs from trying to loop through this string rather than the list containg the string.

So it's like saying

```
for i in 'Hamilton'
```

Rather, you should take its original list:

```
for i in (results_information["MRData"]["StandingsTable"]["StandingsLists"][0]["DriverStandings"]):
            print([0]["Driver"])
```